# attempt to index nil with "clicks" fix?

Tags: lua, roblox

here it is, it is roblox code:

```
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local remoteEvent = replicatedStorage:WaitForChild("AddStats")
local player = game:GetService("Players")
local leaderstats = player:WaitForChild('leaderstats', 10)
local clicks = leaderstats.Clicks
local rebirths = leaderstats.Rebirths

local function clicksStore()
    clicks.Value = clicks.Value + 1
    if rebirths <= 1 then
        clicks.Value = clicks.Value + rebirths.Value
    end
end

remoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(clicksStore)
```

is there anyway i can fix this? its getting on my nerves. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing the leaderstats correctly, but in a server Script, you aren't accessing the player correctly.

You can easily access the player by using the [RemoteEvent's OnServerEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/RemoteEvent/OnServerEvent) connection.

```lua
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local remoteEvent = replicatedStorage:WaitForChild("AddStats")

local function clicksStore(player)
    local leaderstats = player.leaderstats
    local clicks = leaderstats.Clicks
    local rebirths = leaderstats.Rebirths

    local clickValue = 1 + rebirths.Value
    clicks.Value += clickValue
end

remoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(clicksStore)
```